# Can `a?b<c:b>c` be shortened in Javascript?

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

So I have the situation where I have one boolean value `a` and, if that one is `true` and `b<c` I want it to end up as `true`, if `a` is false and `b>c` I want it to resolve as `true` as well. If `b=c` I want it to be always false, no matter the value `b` and `c` are both numbers. My best approach so far is `a?b<c:b>c` or maybe `b^c^a^b<c`. Is there any shorter approach? I can’t stop thinking about it, and want confirmation this is the shortest possible way or find the solution...

Comment: if `a` is `true`, does it matter what is output if `b>c`? same question for `a` being `false` and `b<c`

Comment: Are `b` and `c` guaranteed to be integers?

Comment: @Arnauld yes they are guaranteed integers

Comment: @thejonymyster no it doesn’t matter

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Yes, it can be shorter!

`c-b<a^a` beats `a?b<c:b>c` by 2 bytes. My [tests](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwEEX3PcVfttRA3Ykm9iCiMBkSqJS2JLEb6dljGozCLD7vvXnSSp7dsASxnmK0s0M9mgDCbHGzNHpzQHAvc2/wrvDzGgri2F3SkAp5tG1O/g2XhkvDpQFNvkuahZb0oC9BItRryWd95Z0tbphCvRul8kuT6Fal22L8AA) show that it works for any integer, including negatives. The downside to this formula is that `a` is repeated twice, which may be unideal depending on your situation.

Comment: Very clever. This works for integers because 1) if `a` is false, `c-b<a^a` is true <=> `c-b<a` is true <=> `b>c`; 2) if `a` is true, `c-b<a^a` is true <=> `c-b<a` is false <=> `c-b<1` is false <=> `c-b>=1` is true <=> `b<c`. But it sometimes fails for non-integers.

Comment: I think `c<b+a^a` also works, again for integers.

Comment: What is precedence order for `c-b<a^a`? Is it `((c - b) < a) ^ a`?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 11):

## I don't think it can be any shorter, at least in the most general case

See [dingledooper's 7-bytes solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249015/78410) that works for integers.

If the target expression were `a?b<c:b>=c` (note the change on the second comparison), the two conditions are exactly the opposite, and we can get away with comparing `b` and `c` only once with `a^b>=c` or `!a^b<c`.

**But,** the target is `a?b<c:b>c`, and since `b<c` and `b>c` cannot be inferred from each other, you either need to

- mention `b` and `c` twice each, to carry out two separate comparisons, or
- somehow use the three states (negative, zero, positive) of `b-c`.

For the first method, you already have the optimal answer. For the second, the best I can get is `(c-b)*(a-.5)>0`, 14 bytes ([TIO](https://tio.run/##XcrBCgIhEIDh@z7F3FbDWbq4h4jtQcTDaBqF7IRal@jZDSJC9vjx/zd6UvH5eq@48jm0FjmDSKGCIQVOgbfAEYyJlEpQoBXMVkFH3XH@seZH9/7Vte9pJbwGAM9r4RSmxBdBJ3f0B7d4uQnCo5M7QThpuey3dUTEUQ7v1j4)).

Also note that [`b^c^a^b<c` doesn't quite work](https://tio.run/##XcqxCsIwFEbhvU/xb20gcWsHEX2QkEByTUQJvdKkLuKzRxGR0PHwnZt7uEzL9V7UzOdQa@QFQwoF2kl4CTLgCK2jSzlIjBKTkWhybHL6ZVnW5v1XY9/TCDw7gHjOnMIu8WVwJ3@gvT@S2IC3ZJ394BZ6pVQvuletbw).

Comment: Javascript numbers are floating point, so have 4 states (negative, zero, positive, NaN).  Similarly, the relation between a pair of numbers can be above, below, equal, or unordered (one or both NaN).  It can still be interesting to golf the case of finite numbers, though, so you can exclude NaN inputs, and the case of `inf-inf` giving `NaN`.